# Prevent Visual Studio from adding extra asterisks when hitting enter inside a multiline comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If you are coding C# inside visual studio, and you have a multiline comment, thusly:

```
/*
This is a very interesting comment
that consists of multiple lines
*/
```

Then if you are inside the comment, like after the word "comment" in my example, and you hit enter, Visual Studio adds a "* " on the new line and places your cursor even with the "*" that started the comment.

I hate this behavior.  It is never what I want.  Any way to turn it off?  I wandered through the editor options but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strangely enough this behavior is tied to XML doc comment generation in the C# editor.  If you disable XML doc comment generation it will also disable the auto-generation of the `*` in multi-line comments

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced
- Uncheck "Generate XML doc comments ..."

Comment: Ew.  That is weird.  I don't want to get rid of XML doc comments.  I guess I'm stuck.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: +1 for being the carrier of obtuse knowledge. I expected this question would go unanswered. Kudos.

Comment: @Tergiver strangely you'll find other behaviors are tied to this option in both VB and C# (in VB toggling this option can alter intellisense behavior).

Comment: +1 - Thanks! At last a solution to a really irritating bug! BTW, my addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) provides an enhanced /// auto-comment behaviour that overrides the default Visual Studio behaviour - it's unaffected by this options setting, so it allows you to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Been using GhostDoc for XML comments so this doesn't feel like a major loss. I recommend it to anyone who currently relies on '///'.

Comment: For future reference, in VS 2015, in this same section there is now a separate option named "Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /* */ comments"

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019 (v16.11.16), disable as follows:

- Tools > Options Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Comments
- Untick `Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /* */ comments`

At time of writing, I don't know how to turn this off for C/C++ code.

### Note to the Visual Studio development team

In general, auto-completion should be off by default. They are more nuisance than helpful. Modern development requires the use of a large variety of tools, from text editors, to search tools, to command-line apps, to IDEs...sometimes several of each category. Auto-completion, where any is implemented, is highly variable. Muscle-memory dictates that auto-completion should be as consistent as possible i.e. be turned off.

If a tool offers auto-completion, the developer should have to turn them on explicitly rather than hunt around for a setting to turn it off.